# How can I double loop using filter?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm creating this function that returns only those objects (from an object array) whose property "a" value is not in another array of excluded numbers (which are actually strings)

I realized that I need a double iteration, tried to nest a filter, inside a filter but didn't succeed. I had to hardcode it using the OR operator like this:

```
const arr = [{a:"1"},{a:"2"},{a:"3"}]

const filtered = (arr)=>{
  const ex = ["1","2"]

  return arr.filter(e =>   !e.a.includes(ex[0] || ex[1]))
  
}
console.log(filtered(arr));
```

How can I loop this properly so that I don't have to use the `||` operator?

Comment: That's not how you use the `||` operator. If you need two test in two variables, it should be `!e.a.includes(ex[0]) || !e.a.includes(ex[0])`. Also, `||` should be `&&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const arr = [{a:"1"},{a:"2"},{a:"3"}]

const filtered = (arr)=>{
  const ex = ["1","2"]

  return arr.filter(e => !ex.includes(e.a))
  
}
console.log(filtered(arr));
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need two loops.
You have the `includes` backwards.

```
return arr.filter(e => !ex.includes(e.a))
```

Comment: 1. filter 2. includes - looks like 2 loops to me)

Comment: The OP had multiple calls to `include`, so he was talking about another loop.